# Angular - Cannot see how Angular2 auto updates data from service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I am an Angular2 beginner, creating a test note-taking app. The app is simple: I have a `NotesContianerComponent` which connects to a `NoteService` which has the `getNotes()` and `addNote()` method.

In the `NotesContainerComponent`, I am storing the data returned from service in a member `myNotes` and on `ngOnInit` event, refreshing the array. I am not touching that array anywhere in that code as of now.

Now, when I add a new note using the form and call the service's `addNote()` method from the `NotesContainerComponent`, the note does get added to the backend mock notes array, but at the same time the UI (i.e. `NotesContainerComponent`) gets updated with the new note automatically! I am not doing anything to refresh it manually.

To investigate, I added a `console.log()` to the `getNotes` method of the service, however it is being only called the first time, possibly by `ngOnInit` hook.

What I cannot figure out is, how does Angular2 know about the new note without even querying the service automatically? And how to stop this? Any clues will be appreciated.

`NotesContainerComponent` code for reference:

```
export class NotesContainerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private noteService: NoteService
    ) { }

    addNote(newNote):void {
        this.noteService.add(newNote);
    }

    myNotes: Notes[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.noteService.getNotes()
            .then(notes => this.myNotes = notes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing your mock data in an `Object` or an `Array` and `this.myNotes`'s reference is that `Object`s reference. When your mock datas content changes, all the references will change too. This is because objects are mutable in javascript.

Comment: `myNotes` refers to a local array in the component which can only be updated via the `getNotes()` method .. so that cannot be the case?

Comment: @aditya_m that is exactly the case. You update it with the `add` method and the array changes. Since `this.myNotes` refer to this local array, it also changes.

Comment: The `add` method belongs to the service and it updates the mock array that is present in the service, not the component's local array

Comment: @aditya_m `this.myNotes = notes` check this line. `notes` is your local mock array.

Comment: Oh ok I got it. You mean, in the ngOnInit, I am setting the reference of the local array to the service array, right?

Comment: @aditya_m yes exactly

Comment: Thanks for your help! So I suppose instead of doing that I should copy the elements if I want to maintain the data locally.